Why is my code outputting a value that is one-off the expected value?
In the following code, a user inputs a contribution amount and the program will output how many years it takes for the initial balance to double based on that fixed contribution amount:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const double RATE = 5;
    const double INITIAL_BALANCE = 10000;
    const double TARGET = 2 * INITIAL_BALANCE;

    cout << "Annual contribution: " << endl;
    double contribution; 
    cin >> contribution;

    double balance = INITIAL_BALANCE;
    int year = 0;

    //everything above this sentence must not be changed as per instructor.

    while(balance < TARGET)
    {
        year++;
        balance += balance * RATE/100;
        balance += contribution;
    }

    cout << "Year: " << year << endl;
    cout << "Balance: " << balance << endl;

    return 0;
}

When you run this code, and input the value 100, you get:
Annual contribution:
100
Year: 13
Balance: 20627.8

However, the expected output should have been:
Annual contribution:
100
Year: 13
Balance: 20527.8

What am I doing wrong here? the expected Balance output should have been 20527.8 not 20627.8
Would love to get this resolved!

Changing formula to if (balance < TARGET) balance += contribution;, you would get expected result... Not sure it is the expected change hough ;-)

A good [mre] rarely requires user input. Instead of reading contribution from cin, initialize it to the demo value (double contribution = 100;). Yes, I see the comment "must not be changed as per instructor". However, that applies only to your homework, not to what you post on Stack Overflow. Go ahead and simplify the code for your question.

What is the expected and actual value of balance at the end of the first iteration of your while loop?

If you print out the balance (separately) after compounding by the rate and after adding the annual contribution (using cout << year << "\t" << balance << endl;):
Annual contribution: 
100
1   10500
1   10600
2   11130
2   11230
3   11791.5
3   11891.5
4   12486.1
4   12586.1
5   13215.4
5   13315.4
6   13981.1
6   14081.1
7   14785.2
7   14885.2
8   15629.5
8   15729.5
9   16515.9
9   16615.9
10  17446.7
10  17546.7
11  18424.1
11  18524.1
12  19450.3
12  19550.3
13  20527.8
13  20627.8
Year: 13
Balance: 20627.8

You would see that you had actually achieved 20527.8 as expected.
So what you need to do is likely to check the balance again before adding contribution.
while(balance < TARGET)
{
    year++;
    balance += balance * RATE/100;
    
    if (balance < TARGET) {
        balance += contribution;
    }
}

This will achieve the expected output:
Annual contribution: 
100
Year: 13
Balance: 20527.8

As to why the contribution should not be factored in despite the year passing, you would have to go back to the original question.

I'm guessing this:
while(balance < TARGET)
{
    year++;
    balance += balance * RATE/100;
    balance += contribution;
}

Should assume we don't do another contribution after interest compounds and reaches target
while(balance < TARGET)
{
    year++;
    balance += balance * RATE/100;
    
    if (balance < TARGET)
    {
        balance += contribution;
    }
}

